# Create multiple tiles in Universal Windows 10 Store app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Is there a way to dynamically create multiple tiles in one Universal Windows 10 Store App and how can we set app entry point when press on each tile(where to go in app), is there a listener for tile on click?

P.s. multiple different tiles not different sizes

Comment: You can allow the user to pin various parts of your app as tiles, but you can't create multiple tiles without the user choosing to because you will not pass the store certification

Comment: ok suppose that I'll give the choice to user how many tiles wants to use, but how can I listen which title was pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You can create secondary tiles using `Windows.UI.StartScreen.SecondaryTile`

First check if the tile already exists using static method SecondaryTile.Exists:

```
if (!SecondaryTile.Exists(tileId))
```

tileId is a string that you create to uniquely identify your secondary tiles.

Create a new secondary tile:

```
var secondaryTile = new SecondaryTile(tileId, displayName, arguments,
                               _squareLogoUri, TileSize.Square150x150);

bool isPinned = await secondaryTile.RequestCreateAsync();
```

Here is an example of navigating to part of application the entry tile is linked to when using Prism and your app inherits from `PrismUnityApplication`:

```
protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Arguments))
    {
        // The app was launched from a Secondary Tile
        // Navigate to the item's page
        NavigationService.Navigate("ItemDetail", args.Arguments);
    }
    else
    {
        // Navigate to the initial page
        NavigationService.Navigate("Hub", null);
    }

    Window.Current.Activate();
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```